# How can I prevent LaTeX from breaking words and wrapping them to the next line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

I want to have my entire document fully justified but without the words being broken up and hyphenated at the end of a line if it is too long. I have come across the `\raggedright` argument which prevents the hyphenation, but I'm not sure how to then justify the text.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}%%%%
```

Answer (score 9):

Having both no hyphenation and text flush to both sides puts real stress on spacing.  Compare:

```
Quisque quis  nisl eu nibh  suscipit 
rutrum.     Suspendisse     potenti. 
Maecenas   quis   neque   ut   velit 
pellentesque commodo. Donec et nulla
tortor.
```

with

```
Quisque  quis nisl  eu nibh  suscipit 
rutrum.  Suspendisse  potenti.  Maec-
enas quis neque ut velit pellentesque 
commodo. Donec et nulla tortor.
```

If you are not using Luatex, try it: good
microtyography can minimise or eliminate hyphenation.  Herbert's answer, `usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`, can be used together with microtypography.

Comment: using `\ttfamily` is not a good idea

Comment: @Herbert: The above was represented in HTML, not Tex, and there's only the option of monospaced fonts there.  I guess proportional spacing could be counted as a crude form of microtypography.

Comment: +1 for telling that flush + no hyphenation has severe drawbacks.

Comment: did you produce the example by hand, or is there some automatic way of doing that?

Comment: @Bruno: I used some Emacs Lisp code to set flush to column width, and put the hyphenation in by hand.